# Install my nodejs script to linux bin

Tags: node.js, command-line

If I has my own custom [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) script called do.js that run as a command line application that process parameters like the following:

```
node do.js arg1 arg2 arg3
```

How can I install this application to bin that I run it like:

```
do arg1 arg2 arg3
```

How this can be done ?

Answer (score 1):

First, the word `do` is a reserved word in both bash and zsh shells as part of the for/while looping constructs as `for word in foo bar; do echo $word;done`. So that specific word is not a good choice. Try maybe "go" or "yo" instead. :-)

But there are a few options to make it feel like a normal executable.

- install it without the filename extension in a directory on the PATH such as `/usr/local/bin/yo`. Make the first line of the script a shebang line: `#!/usr/bin/env node`,  and make it executable with `chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/yo`. Reload your shell (`hash -r` or `exec $SHELL`) and you should be up and running.
- Or just use an alias: `alias yo="node yo.js"`.